# How can I generate data insight using dynamic query in power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I want to generate a power bi report that will accept a parameter of its dynamic query from user and process the data based on new user Input, is there any possible way to achieve this in power bi desktop?

Pre-Requisite 
I am using a data source “http:link.com/{new file name}” where {new file name} is the user input I am accepting from the user.
Data is saved online in csv format and not in power Bi, will be fetched on the execution of query.

What I am able to do 
I have created a query that works on data modification in my desired manner, I have to manually update the file name in link used in query, then I have to manually generate the visualization for it which makes it a 3 step process

What I want to do
I want the above manual interaction to be as minimum as possible
If possible, create a dynamic query/ function which will accept the new file name and will apply the query for data modification and based on that data generate the data insight/visualization.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where does the CSV file live that the user specifies? Do you want this parameter to work in the Service or only on PowerBI Desktop?

Comment: The CSV file is coming from a file server , I want this parameter to work in power bi desktop.